# Is it possible to use Windows Passthrough Authentication in a Blazor WebAssembly Project?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, windows-authentication

I have set up a Blazor WebAssembly project using the Visual Studio template and am trying to make it work using Windows Authentication. The final project is meant to run on an IIS Server with Kerberos, which is why I am trying to run it locally using the "IIS-Express" option.

However, no matter which solution I have tried, I always end up with an "401.2 - Unauthorized" error page with the error code "0x80070005", indicating that something about the authentication configuration is not setup correctly.

I have added the authorization core in my `Program.cs`

```cs
using CodeDB_Blazor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddOptions();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

The `issSettings` section of my `launchSettings.json` looks like this:

```json
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44338",
      "sslPort": 44313
    }
  }
```

I have also attempted to add the following `web.config`, but this also changed nothing:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

As far as I had understood, passthrough authentication should be possible in this setup.
I also have an old WebForms application running on the same device using Windows Authentication without any problems.

Comment: This is really two questions. The question *text* ask about ASP.NET Core authentication in general. This is described in [Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). It's easier to set this up in IIS (you can enable it as a Windows Feature). You can use the IIS GUI to set up authentication and test it. IIS Express only runs while debugging. In the server app you need to add `builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();`

Comment: The question *title* though is the real problem - Windows Authentication isn't a good option for any SPA, not just Blazor. The docs explicitly warn against this. The *server* authenticates the *end user/browser*, not individual tabs and the applications that run in them. That means *another* application can call your host's (server's) APIs because, as far as IIS/ASP.NET Core knows, the *user* is authenticated. That's why the docs describe *other* options. A *slightly* more secure option would be to call an authenticated API on the server to retrieve a token that's used in subsequent calls.

Comment: Does your organization use Azure AD? In that case you could integrate Azure AD authentication *and* use the Windows accounts. In Azure AD authentication the end user is recognized because the Azure and local accounts are the same BUT auth tokens are only created per-application.